# CSS - Inner div not taking available height

Tags: css

Having a bit of a mare with this but it should be so simple, I need my `.qualification-delete-container` `div` to take 100% of the parent `div`.

I've attached a fiddle so you can see. If you reduce the screen size, when the content of the `.qualification-row-details` `div` (the turquoise one) takes up 2 lines then the `.qualification-delete-container` (yellow one) needs to respond and take the new height of the parent.

Both of the child div's are `display:inline-block`

```css
.qualification-row {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color:green;
}

.qualification-row-details {
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: turquoise;
}

.qualification-delete-container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 55px;
  vertical-align: top;
  min-height: 100%;
  float: unset;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.flex-vertical-center {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<div class="qualification-row js-qualification-row">
  <div class="qualification-row-details">
    degree type, classification, Course title, year, awarding instition
  </div>
  <div class="qualification-delete-container">
    <div class="flex-vertical-center">
      <a class="qualification-delete">delete</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox to the rescue.

Comment: add `display:flex` to class `qualification-row`

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something silly I was missing but spent way too long on it @RajeevRanjan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your qualification-row css to -

```
.qualification-row {
  display : flex; // ADD DISPLAY FLEX
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color:green;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using display table. I have solved it by using display table and table cell. please have a  look .

I've attached a fiddle so you can see.

```css
.qualification-row {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  background-color:green;
  display: table;
}

.qualification-row-details {
  width: calc(100% - 60px);
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;

}

.qualification-delete-container {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 55px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  min-height: 100%;
  float: unset;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
}
.qualification-row-details-text {
  margin: 10px 10px 10px 0;
  background-color: turquoise;
}
```

```html
<br/>
<div class="qualification-row js-qualification-row">
  <div class="qualification-row-details">
    <div class="qualification-row-details-text">
    degree type, classification, Course title, year, awarding instition
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="qualification-delete-container">
      <a class="qualification-delete">delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew this was an option as I've used this method for older browser support. The other answer has less keyboard wear involved though :)